# Android App Bundle Functionality Mismatch

Tags: android, nativescript, android-bundle

In my Nativescript application, I display something like following:

`Item 1 of 10`

`Item 2 of 10`

`....`

`Item 10 of 10`

For which, I have following code which works just fine normally

```
<ListView id="listView" items="{{ items }}" itemTemplateSelector="$index">
    <ListView.itemTemplate>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label marginTop="20" textAlignment="center" fontWeight="Bold">
                <Label.formattedText>
                    <FormattedString>
                        <FormattedString.spans>
                            <span text="Item " />
                            <span text="{{ $index + 1 }}"/>
                            <span text=" Of "/>
                            <span text="{{$parents['ListView'].items, $parents['ListView'].items.length }}" />
                        </FormattedString.spans>
                    </FormattedString>
                </Label.formattedText>
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </ListView.itemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

but when I release the Android App Bundle as mentioned at https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tooling/publishing/android-app-bundle this produces something like following:

`Item 1 of [Object, Object]`

`Item 2 of [Object, Object]`

`....`

`Item 10 of [Object, Object]`

Does anyone know how to handle this case and why the functionality differs from the normal one?

Comment: When you say app bundle are you referring to `--bundle` option?

Comment: No its not webpack bundle. Its Android bundle which is generated using --aab.

Comment: is there any other way of writing the collection length under ListView?

Comment: Why not use the following instead? <span text="{{$parents['ListView'].items.length }}" />

Comment: I will try that out. I deliberately added $parents['ListView'].items because it used to log some warning if I did the way you suggested.

Comment: I tried that but no luck. It still gives me same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in nativescript. I have raised an issue https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/7449 for the same.